# Перегрузка оператора сложения

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, function-overloading

```
class Cat {
private:
    int value = 1;

public:
    Cat(int _value) {
        value = _value;
    }

    operator+(Cat a, Cat b) {
        return new Cat(a.value + b.value);
    }
};
```

Казалось бы все пишу правильно, сложение двух котов даст нового кота, у которого value будет суммой их value'ов. Но получаю две ошибки.

```
main.cpp:17:5: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    operator+(Cat a, Cat b) {
    ^
main.cpp:18:16: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'Cat *'
        return new Cat(a.value + b.value);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

А кто будет объявлять тип возвращаемого значения?

```
Cat* operator+(Cat a, Cat b) {
    return new Cat(a.value + b.value);
}
```

Только это - во-первых, не решение, а во-вторых, плохое решение.

Не решение - потому что вообще оператор `+` бинарный. Он складывает **два** значения, а у вас в сложении участвуют **три** - еще и ваш объект (`this`).

```
Cat* operator+(Cat b) {
    return new Cat(this->value + b.value);
}
```

Теперь это решение. Но плохое. Потому что возвращает не кота, а указатель на него. В результате на вызывающую функцию перекладывается ответственность за обязательное сохранение значения и освобождение в дальнейшем памяти.

Этого можно избежать, если возвращать готового кота:

```
Cat operator+(Cat b) {
    return Cat(this->value + b.value);
}
```

И последнее. Если кот большой (не в смысле значения `value`, а занимает много памяти) - то имеет смысл передавать его в оператор не по значению, а по ссылке:

```
Cat operator+(const Cat& b) {
    return Cat(this->value + b.value);
}
```

Comment: ВООООТ!!! ВООООТ!!!!! ВОТ ЗА ЧТО Я ЛЮБЛЮ СТАК ОВЕРФЛОУ)!!! ПАСИБО ХАРРИ =) Кстати а вопрос, аргумент "b" он будет слева от плюса или справа?

Comment: Справа, конечно.

Comment: А то что там всякие левосторонние, правосторонние компиляторы есть, это все можно вообще не думать об этом в 2017 году уже?

Comment: Вы про альфа/бета изомеры компиляторов?

Comment: Справа. запись `a.operator+(b)` эквивалентна записи `a+b`. Второй вопрос не очень понял... вы имеете в виду сами грамматики? Но это не имеет отношения к данному вопросу. Здесь важно знать, что C++, позволяя перегружать операторы, не меняет ни их "арность" (бинарный будет бинарным и т.д.), ни ассоциативность - так что, как бы вы не переопределяли операторы + и *, например, `a+b*c` будет эквивалентно `a.operator+(b.operator*(c))`.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus, повеселили, спасибо )

Comment: @isnullxbh я не знаю че тя веселит, но есть левосторонние компиляторы а есть правосторонние, так как стандарт не указывает какой операнд будет вычисляться первым правый или левый. Я по этому и уточнил может ли это влиять на то какой аргумент придет к нам в метод сложения, правый или левый. Не понимаю что тебя так смешит) Скорее ВЫ меня повеселили)

Comment: @Harry пасиба, я имел ввиду если компилятор правосторонний или левостороонний влияет ли это на то какой аргумент придет к нам в b)

Comment: О все, я нагуглил ответ: В C++ не существует понятия вычисления слева направо или справа налево, что не нужно путать с левосторонней (left-to-right) или правосторонней (right-to-left) ассоциативностью операторов: выражение f1() + f2() + f3() разбирается как (f1() + f2()) + f3() за счёт левоассоциативности operator+, но вызов функции f3 может быть вычислен первым, последним, или между f1() и f2() во время выполнения.

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus, да нет же, нет такого понятия "левосторонний компилятор".

Comment: Ну по этому я и употребил слово "всякие" потому как не вдавался в этот вопрос и тем более термины не учил), уже прогуглился, понял что приоритет операторов четко стандартизирован. Все, всем спасибо)

Answer (score 5):

Бинарный оператор, такой как, например, оператор сложения `operator +`должен быть определен либо как нестатическая функция - член класса с одним параметром, либо как функция, которая не является членом класса, с двумя параметрами.

Выданные вам сообщения компилятора

```
main.cpp:17:5: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    operator+(Cat a, Cat b) {
    ^
main.cpp:18:16: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'Cat *'
        return new Cat(a.value + b.value);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

говорят о том, что у определенного вами оператора отсутствует тип возвращаемого значения.

Тип возвращаемого значения может отсутствовать только у функций преобразования. В случае же оператора сложения вы обязаны указать тип возвращаемого значения.

При сложении двух объектов класса не имеет никакого смысла возвращать указатель на объект. В этому случае вы не сможете связывать операторы сложения в цепочку без применения дополнительных операторов, и, более того, это может привести к утечке памяти.

Оператор должен возвращать сам объект либо с квалификатором `const` либо без него.

Как уже выше упомянуто, оператор может быть объявлен как нестатическая функция-член класса с одним параметром.

В этом случае оператор `operator +` может выглядеть так

```
class Cat 
{
private:
    int value = 1;

public:
    Cat(int _value) 
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    Cat operator +( const Cat &a ) const 
    {
        return Cat( this->value + a.value );
    }
};
```

либо как

```
class Cat 
{
private:
    int value = 1;

public:
    Cat(int _value) 
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    const Cat operator +( const Cat &a ) const 
    {
        return Cat( this->value + a.value );
    }
};
```

Вы могли бы перегрузить оператор также для `rvalue`-ссылок, как, например,

```
Cat operator +( const Cat &&a ) const 
{
    return Cat( this->value + a.value );
}
```

или

```
Cat operator +( Cat &&a ) const 
{
    return Cat( this->value + a.value );
}
```

но для такого простого класса, который не захватывает большие ресурсы,  это значения не имеет.

Обратите внимание на присутствие квалификатора `condt` после списка параметров. Это говорит о том, что сам объект, который будет присутствовать в левой части от оператора, изменяться не будет, так же, как и правый объект, так как соответствующий ему параметр оператора определен также с квалификатором `const`.

Имейте в виду, так как конструктор класса объявлен как преобразующий конструктор, то вы в этом случае можете складывать объекты класса `Cat` с числами. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

class Cat 
{
private:
    int value = 1;

public:
    Cat(int _value) 
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    const Cat operator +( const Cat &a ) const 
    {
        return Cat( this->value + a.value );
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Cat c1( 10 );

    c1 + 5.5;

    return 0;
}
```

Насколько это оправдано - это решать вам, исходя из того, какой смысл вкладывается в этот оператор сложения. Если вы не хотите допускать такого неявного преобразования из числа в объект класса `Cat`, то вы можете объявить конструктор, как явный. В этом случае программа не будет компилироваться, если имеет попытка сложить объект класса `Cat` с числом.

```
#include <iostream>

class Cat 
{
private:
    int value = 1;

public:
    explicit Cat(int _value) 
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    const Cat operator +( const Cat &a ) const 
    {
        return Cat( this->value + a.value );
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Cat c1( 10 );

    c1 + 5.5;

    return 0;
}
```

Для этой программы компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке на подобие следующего

```
prog.cpp:24:5: error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Cat' and 'double')
  c1 + 5.5;
     ^
```

Второй способ объявить этот оператор - это объявить его как функцию, которая не является членом класса. Так как эта функция должна иметь доступ к закрытому члену класса `value`, то ее нужно будет объявить как дружественную функцию класса.

Саму функцию вы можете определить как внутри определения класса, так и вне его.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>

class Cat 
{
private:
    int value = 1;

public:
    Cat(int _value) 
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    friend const Cat operator +( const Cat &a, const Cat &b )  
    {
        return Cat( a.value + b.value );
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Cat c1( 10 );
    Cat c2( 5 );

    Cat c3 = c1 + c2;

    return 0;
}
```

Имейте в виду, что это плохая идея объявлять переменные, начинающиеся с подчеркивания. В общем случае такие имена, начинающиеся с подчеркивания, зарезервированы за компилятором.

Принято для параметров конструктора присваивать те имена, которые соответствуют именам членов класса. В этом случае сразу же видно, какой параметр какой член класса инициализирует. Поэтому вы могли бы определить конструктор следующим образом

```
Cat( int value ) : value( value )
{
}
```

Если член класса `value` не может принимать отрицательные значения, то лучше его и соответствующий параметр конструктора объявить, как имеющие тип `unsigned int`.

Comment: шикарнейший ответ) спасибо огромное

Comment: @Maxmaxmaximus Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 0):

Используя `friend`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( int p_a )
        : m_a( p_a )
    {}

    int getA() const { return m_a; }

protected:
    int m_a;

friend Foo operator+( Foo const& lF, Foo const& rF )
{
    return Foo( lF.m_a + rF.m_a );  
}

};


int main() {

    Foo f1( 12 ), f2( 13 ), f4( 14 );

    Foo f3 = f1 + f2 + f4;

    std::cout << f3.getA() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```